# Converting embedded JSON into flat table - increasing efficiency

Tags: python, json, csv

I am new Python user, who decided to use Python to create simple application that allows for converting json files into flat table and saving the output in cvs format. I was wondering if you could give me some advice how I could improve my code to make it work in more efficient way. I am asking since if I convert relatively small files everything works just fine but when I try to convert ~200 MB file it starts to take a while. I am afraid that when I begin to work with bigger files it might take quite some time to convert my datasets.

Here is my code, which I created with help of [this](https://medium.com/@amirziai/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10#.efnouzihr) great blog post about flattening json objects:

```
import sys, os, json, tkFileDialog, tkMessageBox
from Tkinter import *
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

def openFile():
    currdir = os.getcwd()
    filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(
        initialdir = currdir,
        title='Please select a file',
        filetypes=[('JSON file','.json')])

    return filename

def loading_file(path):
    #File path
    file_path = path

    #Loading json file
    json_data = open(file_path)
    data = json.load(json_data)
    return data

#Function that recursively extracts values out of the object into a flattened dictionary
def flatten_json(data):
    flat = [] #list of flat dictionaries
    def flatten(y):
        out = {}

        def flatten2(x, name=''):
            if type(x) is dict:
                for a in x:
                    if a == "name":
                            flatten2(x["value"], name + x[a] + '_')
                    else:
                        flatten2(x[a], name + a + '_')
            elif type(x) is list:
                for a in x:
                    flatten2(a, name + '_')
            else:
                out[name[:-1]] = x

        flatten2(y)
        return out

#Loop needed to flatten multiple objects
    for i in range(len(data)):
        flat.append(flatten(data[i]).copy())

    return json_normalize(flat)




#Outputing normalized data into csv
def csv_out(data, path):
    #creating csv file name
    name = '~/Desktop/' + os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(path)[0]) + '.csv'
    #converting to the csv
    data.to_csv(name, encoding='utf-8') #'~/Desktop/out.csv'

def done():
   tkMessageBox.showinfo('json2csv',"DONE!")

def main():
    filepath = openFile()
    data_file = loading_file(filepath)
    table = flatten_json(data_file)
    csv_out(table, filepath)
    done()

### Application Interface ###
tk = Tk()

#Creating window:
tk.geometry('250x150+600+300')
tk.title('JSON2CSV')

#Creating convert button
convertbutton = Button(tk, text = 'Convert to .csv', command = main)
convertbutton.place(x = 25, y = 50)



tk.mainloop()
```

Here you will find short and **simplistic** example of the json structure I work with:

```
[{
 "_id": {
   "id": "123"
 },
 "device": {
   "browser": "Safari",
   "category": "d",
   "os": "Mac"
 },
 "exID": {
   "$oid": "123"
 },
 "extreme": false,
 "geo": {
   "city": "London",
   "country": "United Kingdom",
   "countryCode": "UK",
   "ip": "00.000.000.0"
 },
 "viewed": {
   "$date": "2011-02-12"
 },
 "attributes": [{
   "name": "gender",
   "numeric": 0,
   "value": 0
 }, {
   "name": "email",
   "value": false
 }],
 "change": [{
   "id": {
     "$id": "1231"
   },
   "seen": [{
     "$date": "2011-02-12"
   }]
 }]
}, {
 "_id": {
   "id": "456"
 },
 "device": {
   "browser": "Chrome 47",
   "category": "d",
   "os": "Windows"
 },
 "exID": {
   "$oid": "345"
 },
 "extreme": false,
 "geo": {
   "city": "Berlin",
   "country": "Germany",
   "countryCode": "DE",
   "ip": "00.000.000.0"
 },
 "viewed": {
   "$date": "2011-05-12"
 },
 "attributes": [{
   "name": "gender",
   "numeric": 1,
   "value": 1
 }, {
   "name": "email",
   "value": true
 }],
 "change": [{
   "id": {
     "$id": "1231"
   },
   "seen": [{
     "$date": "2011-02-12"
   }]
 }]
}]
```

Comment: Speaking of flattening, I'd recommend against using a bunch of nested function definitions. In my experience, there's usually a better way in python. Especially in this case where you're not even making use of the bindings in the outer functions' scope. It would make your program more readable to just have each function do one clear task (and do it well) and make a call to the helpers. In my opinion the modicum of encapsulation you get from nested function definition rarely outweighs the loss in readability. [Zen of Py: "Flat is Better Than Nested."](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: Thank you, I will try to make it more readable and follow Peters advice.

Answer (score 1):

@machine-yearning is right. Try to avoid the nesting--that gets ugly quickly.

Here is my stab at trying to help you along:

```
import json
import csv

def get_ids(data):
    ids = []
    for datum in data: 
        id = datum["_id"]["id"]
        ids.append(id)
    return ids

def get_devices(data):
    devices = []

    for datum in data:
        browser = datum["device"]["browser"]
        category = datum["device"]["category"]        
        os = datum["device"]["os"]
        devices.append([browser, category, os])
    return devices

def flatten_json(json_file, output_fn):
    data = json.loads(json_file)
    flattened_data =[]

    ids = get_ids(data)
    devices = get_devices(data)

    for id, device in zip(ids, devices):
        browser, category, os = device
        flattened_data.append([id, browser,category,os])
    with open(output_fn, 'ab') as my_csv:
        csv_file = csv.writer(my_csv, delimiter=',')
        csv_file.writerows(flattened_data)  
    return "FLATTENED DATA SAVED"

# example to make this run:
flatten_json(x, "my_flattened_file.csv")
```

You of course need to make a function which gets the json data from a website or from a stored file. Looking at your data sample, you can make a function for geo and attributes which is similar to **get_devices** and then just include them like I did in the **flatten_json** function as I did with the others.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ ansebbian0 thank you for your answer but I do not want to create file specific flattening function, because data structure is quite irregular. Furthermore, there are around 1000 different characteristics/attributes and it makes no sense to feed them one by one. That is why I used the nesting to make it as generic as possible (the only exemption in function if key == 'name'). I am sorry if it was not clear.

Comment: @Aneconomist. No worries. Anyway, just to give you some ideas, you could try to modify the get functions to be general to take the specific type of key:pair structures which are in your data. These keys could be retrieved by using a for loop to get all of the keys (make these dictionaries for the ones like device) and store them in a list. After that, you could loop over these stored keys/ key:dictionaries to recover the data in the flatten_json function. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I will try to follow your example to improve as much as I can.